# unable to use the paste function with the columns of a dataframe in ggplot 2

Tags: r

This is my problem:

this part of my script works:

```
paste(fileIn$DOY_L8,fileIn$type, sep="")
```

but not in this way

```
sat = "L8"
paste(fileIn$(paste("DOY_",sat,sep="")),fileIn$type, sep="")
```

The question is: it is possible to use the function "paste" after the $ ??

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use `paste` function like that. To get what you want, you can break it in two steps:

- Create a variable that has the name of the column you want to derive.
  If `sat<-'L8'` then,

  ```
  col1<-paste("DOY_", sat, sep="")
  ```
- Now you can use:

  ```
  fileIn[,col1]
  ```

Comment: Dear Max, I know I look stupid, but I'm new in this community and I don't know how to quote your answer. Any hint? Thank you

Comment: :) There is a tick next to my answer on the left. near the 0

Comment: Wow, I can see the up and down arrows above and below the 0 only if I open the website in chrome. Anyway I think I voted. Do you confirm this?